# Coding Style: Two activities with mostly same code but different content view

Tags: android, coding-style

I have two activities that have the same code. The main difference is that they have different content views (and therefore a few different elements).

What is recommended? Should I leave it like it is in two activities or should I make it one activity and and solve it using if else queries each time when there is something about the view (e.g. setcontentview and a few (5) other view related code blocks)?

For example

```
if (isLandscape) { //landscape looks different than portrait
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landscape);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal);
}
```

Is this recommended / good coding style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting different views for portrait and landscape this can be done through the resource files using a layout-land directory and adding the new activity layout with the same name in the landscape directory.

So you would have a activity.xml file in both the layout and layout-land folder.

To answer your question in general though, it works well to use a member variable in your activity to distinguish between your two cases. Then when you need to do something based on the state of this variable using the if/else logic.

For example, using a separate layout with a unique view container on tablets. You could check `if(findViewById(R.id.tablet_container)) != null)` then you would set your isTabletView member variable to true or false based on this. Any time you needed to do something based on if the app is being run on tablet or phone you can reference this variable.

Comment: I forgot about layout-land, thank you.  It wasn't just an example: I'm using a popup method for displaying content in landscape, and a normal full screen display method for portrait. So it's basically the same code, but different layouts

Comment: Yeah for that case just sticking your landscape style layout in layout-land and using the exact same file names and id's will allow you to use the same code for both instances!